# Printing more than one image (per line) in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, flask, praw

I am having trouble with an application that I built. Basically what it does is if it detects the name of a country in a string(submission.title), then it will print the flag of that country after the title. So if the title was 'China is building a rocket' it would have the Chinese flag printed right after the word rocket. 
The problem is that it won't print more than one flag. So if the title was 'China and Russia are building rockets' it would only print either the Chinese flag or the Russian flag. Not both. I want it to be able to print both flags.

Thank you

Python script

```
news = []
i = 0
for submission in redditFunction(time, limit=int(num) ):
    i += 1
    for j in country: #j = country name
        if j in submission.title: 
            flag = "static/flags/" + country[j].lower() + ".png"
            news.append([str(i) + '. ' + submission.title, submission.url, flag] )
            break
    else:
        news.append([str(i) + '. ' + submission.title, submission.url]) #no flag will be printed

return render_template("index.html", news=news)
```

HTML

```
{% for item in news %}                            
     <h2> <a href= "{{item[1]}}">{{item[0]}}</a> <img src= "{{item[2]}}"  style="width:25px;height:18.25px;">  </h2> 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

`break` in the country loop is preventing you from having all the flags.

As you may have more than one flag per item, you should use a `list` to keep relevant flag urls in the item object (you implemented it as a `list`)

**view**

```
news = []
i = 0
for submission in redditFunction(time, limit=int(num)):
    i += 1

    # flags list will be empty in case of no match
    flags = []
    for j in country: #j = country name -- consider renaming 'j' to 'country_name'
        if j in submission.title:  # you may consider checking with lower()/upper()
            flags.append("static/flags/" + country[j].lower() + ".png")

    news.append([str(i) + '. ' + submission.title, submission.url, flags])

return render_template("index.html", news=news)
```

Having a list of flags, inside the template, you just need to iterate over it and add an img element per flag.

**template**

```
{% for item in news %}
    <h2>
        <a href= "{{item[1]}}">{{item[0]}}</a>
        {% for flag in index[2] %}
            <img src= "{{ flag }}"  style="width:25px;height:18.25px;">
        {% endfor %}
    </h2> 
{% endfor %}
```

Please note that I haven't tested the solution, so please let me know if you hit an error.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest moving this logic into your view logic and keep your controller simple.

```
# controller
return render_template('index.html', 
                       submissions=redditFunction(time, limit=int(num)),
                       countries=countries)

# view 
{% for submission in submissions %}

<h2>
    <a href="{{ submission.url }}">{{loop.index}}. {{submission.title}}</a>
    {% for country in countries %}
        {% if country in submission.title %}
            {% set country_path = 'flags/%s.jpg' % country %}
            <img src={{ url_for('static', filename=country_path) }}>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

This makes your view logic much more understandable. Otherwise you have to go back to re-reference what `item[0]` and `item[1]` are. You also get some nice things in Jinja like `loop.index` for creating the numbered titles.

I tested this in Flask and it looks to work correctly.